# avoid for loop of a sequential process

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following sequential R code:

```
w.1 <- diag(seq(1:7))
ut.mat <- cbind(diag(3), -1*rbind(c(1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,1)))
x <- matrix(rnorm(7), 7, 1)
lhs.l <- ut.mat %*% w.1 %*% t(ut.mat)
rhs.l <- ut.mat %*% x

p.0 <- r.0 <- rhs.l
l.0 <- matrix(0, 3, 1)
for(i in 1:3)
{
  a.0 <- (t(r.0) %*% r.0) / (t(p.0) %*% lhs.l %*% p.0)
  l.0 <- l.0 + (a.0[1,1] * p.0)
  r.1 <- r.0 - (a.0[1,1] * lhs.l %*% p.0)
  b.0 <- (t(r.1) %*% r.1) / (t(r.0) %*% r.0)
  p.0 <- r.1 + (b.0[1,1] * p.0)
  r.0 <- r.1
}
```

This is a simple case. but actually ut.mat, x, p.0, l.0 are large in dimension and i is also large.

Use of for loop is time consuming. Any ideas to make this efficient as this is a sequential process I think parallelization is also not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it intentional that `i` does not appear in the body of the loop?

Comment: Yes. Because I don't want to save all the values for p.0, r.0 and l.0. I just want the value of l.0 after 3 iterations (in this case). But usually i is very large.

Comment: One obvious thing is you should store `lhs.l %*% p.0` so you don't have to compute it twice, since it is by far the most consuming operation. I otherwise don't think you can easily get rid of the for loop or parallelize like you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to just calculating *lhs.1%*%p.0* once as flodel suggests, you could replace using matrix operations such as  (t(r.0) %*% r.0)  to calculate the inner product of two vectors with  sum(r.0*r.0)  which is 2. - 2.5 times faster.  You could also eliminate b.0 as a separate variable but this doesn't change the times much.  The modified code would look like

```
shani_faster <- function() {
w.1 <- diag(seq(1:7))
ut.mat <- cbind(diag(3), -1*rbind(c(1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,1)))
x <- matrix(rnorm(7), 7, 1)
lhs.l <- ut.mat %*% w.1 %*% t(ut.mat)
rhs.l <- ut.mat %*% x

p.0 <- r.0 <- rhs.l
l.0 <- matrix(0, 3, 1)
r.1 <- numeric(3)
for(i in 1:3)
{
 lhs.p <- lhs.l %*% p.0
 a.0 <- sum(r.0^2)/sum(p.0*lhs.p)
 l.0 <- l.0 + (a.0 * p.0)
 r.1 <- r.0 - a.0 * lhs.p
 p.0 <- r.1 + sum(r.1^2)/sum(r.0^2) * p.0
 r.0 <- r.1
}
}
```

I've made a function called shani using your original code and called the modified version shani_faster.  The execution times for 10000 executions of the two versions are

```
microbenchmark(shani(), shani_faster(), times=10000)
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq  median      uq       max neval
    shani() 112.352 116.345 118.626 121.191 23799.475 10000
shani_faster()  52.469  55.606  56.747  58.172  1132.928 10000
```

so about a factor of two improvement where most of the reduction is due to the change in the inner product calculation.   I would expect you to see about this factor of improvement for larger vectors.  I agree with the other comments that after this, there's not much you can do with the code.  You might try searching for an R package which implements your algorithm.